# RCTView generated view config for validAttributes does not match native and RCTView generated view config for bubblingEventTypes does not match native

Tags: android, react-native

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lBib.png)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "thelcdbaba",
  "version": "2.4.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^1.0.0",
    "@monadstech/react-native-use-otp-verify": "^1.0.10",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^4.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.7",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^12.9.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.2.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.2",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "color": "^3.1.2",
    "currency-formatter": "^1.5.5",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.10",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
    "i18next": "17.0.16",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "oauth-1.0a": "^2.2.6",
    "password-validator": "^5.0.3",
    "query-string": "^6.12.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-input": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-content-loader": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-dash": "^0.0.11",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.4.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.15",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-otp-textinput": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-phone-input": "https://github.com/rnlab/react-native-phone-input.git",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-razorpay": "^2.2.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-rename": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.17",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.8.1",
    "react-native-wc-api": "^1.1.10",
    "react-native-webview": "^9.0.1",
    "react-native-woocommerce-api": "^1.8.8",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.1.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-heavy-screen": "^1.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-persist-transform-immutable": "^5.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.3.0",
    "validator": "^13.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: change gradle version